# App freeze when I remove [super loadView]

Tags: iphone

When I remove the [super loadView]; the view wont display. The superclass is UIViewController.

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];   

    UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 367.0f) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;
    self.tableView = tableview;
    [tableview release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) [UIViewController Class Reference, loadView section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView)

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

2) You have to set `view` property to something. After all this method is called `loadView` :). Instead of `[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];` try

```
self.view = tableView;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the view programming guide, it mentions that if you override [loadView], you should construct your own view.

default loadView will look at bunch of stuff, like load from nib first, then construct normal view.

So, just construct a view, and assign it to self.view -

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame ...];
self.view = view;
[view release];

then it should be fine.

edit: example with your code:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 367.0f)];
    self.view = view;
    [view release];

    UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 367.0f) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;
    self.tableView = tableview;
    [tableview release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

edit2: link to viewcontroller programming guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1

Look at custom view controller section, Creating the View Programmatically, and few other places in that doc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna move that [ tableview release ] after the addSubview.

Comment: does not help since the property retains it.

Comment: Yeah, I fumbled that one.  Serves me right for trying to answer a question at 3am.  Or 4am.  Darned time change.  =)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you never assign the view property in the code. When in the last line you access the view property, it causes `-loadView` to be called again, which results in a endless loop.