# Is it ok to call [super loadView]?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, loadview

I thought that I should never call [super loadView] but something is confusing me.

In description of loadView ([UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) it is said that "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.",
but in ZoomingPDFViewer example that they gave, loadView implementation ([ZoomingPDFViewerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/Classes_ZoomingPDFViewerViewController_m.html)) is calling [super loadView].

I have tried to call it from my loadView method and it works ok, but I just don't understand then what does it mean to not call super.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You definitely should not be calling `[super loadView]`.  I'd say you found a bug in the ZoomingPDFViewer example.

You override `loadView` when you want to programatically create the view hierarchy for your view controller (not using a xib).

As you pointed out, the docs **clearly** state that you should not call super.

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

I assume this is to avoid loading both from a xib and programatically creating a view as this method is used by the base to load a view from a xib:

> If the view controller has an associated nib file, this method loads
>   the view from the nib file.

Note also that even if during allocation of your `UIViewController` object you pass nil for the nibNameOrNil parameter that the `UIViewController` implementation of `loadView` will try to load any xib with the associated class name in it.

> A view controller has an associated nib file if the nibName property
>   returns a non-nil value, which occurs if the view controller was
>   instantiated from a storyboard, if you explicitly assigned it a nib
>   file using the initWithNibName:bundle: method, **or if iOS finds a nib
>   file in the app bundle with a name based on the view controller’s
>   class name.** If the view controller does not have an associated nib
>   file, this method creates a plain UIView object instead.

The real intent of this method is to give you full control of building the view hierarchy without relying on the built in xib loading mechanism.:

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually.

Personally, I override `loadView` if: 1.) The xib I would make for it is really trivial or 2.) The layout of the control is very dynamic, so creating a xib with a static layout has little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

NSViewController tries to initialize a view from a nib in -loadView. Since your nib name is not set for your controller, it will just give you a self.view = nil; I would assume UIViewController works the same way.

So it should be safe, but you it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: While it should be harmless, if there was a xib with a name based on the view controller name, then calling `[super loadView]` would load that nib into `self.view`.  I've never actually seen this happen (since I never call the super), but based on the docs that's what I'd expect.  Also, I think calling `[super loadView]` would minimally assign a generic view to `self.view`, which is what your code should be doing.  Again this won't hurt anything (assuming the custom implementation of `loadView` assigns a value to `self.view` after calling the super), but it is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a view created in your IB, then you should call [super loadView] in your code to give a view to your program.

In case of your custom views, you are suppose to create a view with the interfaz builder, so you dont need to call it.

Comment: Ok, but what does it mean "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super."?

Comment: it means that you are creating the view, so you dont need to make your super load it

Comment: You give a view to your program by doing something like: `UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]; ... (create view hierarchy) ...  self.view = myView;`  If you aren't assigning `self.view` to a new value, then what's the point of overriding `loadView` to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your ViewController programmatically, you could call `super.loadView()` instead of `self.view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)` at the beginning of `override func loadView()`.

However, do NOT call `self.view` before `super.loadView()`, since the former will trigger the latter if view did not been loaded.

I don't think it's a good idea to explain Apple's documentation like a robot.